# Qt: Force QGraphicsItem to update

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

According to [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#update), **" void QGraphicsItem::update ( const QRectF & rect = QRectF() ) " does not cause an immediate paint**; instead it schedules a paint request that is processed by QGraphicsView after control reaches the event loop. 
Here is my code:

```
this->item->setPixmap( QPixmap::fromImage(*coloration->image) );// QGraphicsPixmapItem 
this->item->update();
this->scene->update(); // QGraphicsScene
this->view->update(); // QGraphicsView
```

and the code is in a method that will be invoked every 100 milliseconds(and in which the coloration->image will change), but the Qt refuses to update the image every 100 milliseconds, and it only renders the final image. So, **how could I paint the item immediately**?

Comment: Did you tried [Animation Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/animation-overview.html)?

Comment: @graphite Actually, my project doesn't produce animation, it just do some processing of an image and then updates the image, so I think animation is not an appropriate option. Do you have any idea how to deal with problem by using QGraphicsItem?

Comment: Do you give control to event loop while processing image?

Comment: @graphite I have test the qApp->processEvents(), but it doesn't work. And in the console mode, I found that the paint isn't invoked!

Comment: @graphite Thanks for your reply! I found that repainting the viewport will do the job! So in the method, just call this->item->setPixmap( QPixmap::fromImage(*coloration->image) ); this->view->viewport()->repaint();

Comment: Calling scene->update() and view->update() every 100ms would be highly inefficient. item->update() should be enough. (if not, there's probably a mistake in the item's implementation)

Comment: @JavaBeta thanks a lot spend so much time one that. And it was viewport. I think you should write this as a answer . And accept it yourself for readers.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
ui->graphicsView->viewport()->repaint();

Answer (score 0):

You must be blocking your event loop, or your implementation of the item is otherwise bad. I can't reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional usage

```
#include <QGraphicsView> 
QGraphicsView *view = scene()->views().first();
view->viewport()->repaint();
```